# Make certain countries visible on Carto map

Tags: postgresql, carto, basemap

I want to show only APAC countries on the carto map. I re-wrote my SQL query (see below) and clicked 'create a dataset from query'. Although the countries specified were coded in colors, those outside of APAC are still visible on the map.

How do I make non-APAC countries non-visible?

```
SELECT * FROM apac WHERE country IN ('Australia', 'Brunei', 'Cambodia', 'China', 'Laos', 'Singapore', 'Malaysia', 'Bangladesh', 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Sri Lanka', 'Philippines', 'New Zealand', 'Indonesia', 'South Korea', 'Taiwan', 'Hong Kong', 'Japan', 'North Korea', 'Pupua New Guinea', 'East Timor', 'Vietnam', 'Myanmar', 'Thailand')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand (and correct me if I am wrong) that when you said:

> (...) those outside of APAC are still visible on the map.

You are viewing those countries in the basemap. So, in order to get rid of the basemap, you have to click on the `Basemap` button on the left-bottom corner of the Editor.

[image]

Then, select a background color ([with good contrast with your layer](https://carto.com/academy/courses/intermediate-design/choose-colors-1/)).

[image]

Comment: No, I want to filter out non-APAC countries so I wrote a SQL query to do that. But I do not think I did it correctly because the non-APAC countries are still visible on the map.

Comment: Sorry @ramiroaznar I do not really understand your instructions. When I click on the 'change basemap' button at the left-bottom corner of the editor, I do not see any background color option.

Comment: I have added a couple of screenshots to show you how to change your basemap to a simple background color.

Comment: You are awesome @ramiroaznar. Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Your welcome! Please check as answered in order to show other people your question is solved. :-)